# Dataframe split

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a big Matrix (3600 row) and 1 column (character) called data and I would like to split the Matrix everytime "Neue Zeitung" appears. I have tried something like to store the index and then do the split. However it does not work

```
    index.mat <- c()
    for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
      if (substr(data[i,1],1,12)=="Neue Zeitung")==T) {
        index.temp <- i
      }
      index.mat <- rbind(index.mat,index.temp)
    }
```

and then use a split function but is it the best way?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need an explicit loop. Instead, you can use `cumsum` and `split`.

#### For exact matches:

```
split(dat, cumsum(dat[,1] == "Neue Zeitung"))
```

#### For partial matching / regex matching:

```
split(dat, cumsum(grepl("Neue Zeitung", dat[,1])))
```

#### For position-based partial matching:

```
split(dat, cumsum(substr(dat[,1], 1, 12) == "Neue Zeitung"))
```

or

```
split(dat, cumsum(grepl("^Neue Zeitung.*", dat[,1])))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `grepl` function might be better suited:

```
index.mat <- which(grepl("Neue Zeitung", data[,1]))
```

Comment: @Pisdom thanks a lot, how wou you adjust the script if only the first 21 rows in data must equals Neue Zeitung? I have tried substring without any success

Comment: Do you mean that the first 21 rows must be exact match while rows after that can be partial match?